# Gazebo Plugin Crashes: undefined Symbol "ZTIN6Gazebo20GazeboCameraUtilsE"

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Gazebo Plugin Crashes with the following error message when model placed in gazebo: undefined Symbol "ZTIN6Gazebo20GazeboCameraUtilsE"

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65403/gazebo-plugin-crashes:-undefined-symbol-%22ztin6gazebo20gazebocamerautilse%22/) by [Seba](https://answers.ros.org/users/5005/seba/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-06-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is in your CMakeLists. Either you don't search for the required package in find_package macro or you don't include the libraries in the target_link_libraries macro

---

Originally posted by [agbj](https://answers.ros.org/users/29369/agbj/) with karma: 83 on 2017-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0